# Inconsistent Array iterator output when logging inside setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am iterating an array iterator using `for..of` and trying to log the value at a  regular interval. My understanding is `let` keyword will create new variable in each iteration(updated after mistake pointed by VLAZ in comment section) and inside the `setIterval` it will get a new value. Instead of this , the log inside the setInterval is printing an inconsistent result which I am not able to understand the cause. Will appreciate if you can help to understand this.

***Edit***: I am aware setTimeout will log a consistent result , but I intended to know why setInterval is logging two result simultaneously and how it is deciding the values

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let [i, v] of numbers.entries()) {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Output - ', v)
  }, 2000 * (i + 1))
}
```

Comment: You are setting a new interval in each iteration of the loop. Did you mean to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: "*My understanding is let keyword will create a closure and inside the setIterval*". No, wrong terminology. `let` will create a *new* variable for each iteration. A closure is basically any function. Including the one given to `setInterval`. If you used `var` the callback would still be a closure but there would only be one set of `i` and `v` variables, so when the function executes it will read them and there would be a single value for each single variable. With `let` there are *many* variables called `i` and `v`. Imagine you just have `i0`, `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4` - totally separate.

Comment: "*I intended to know why setInterval is logging two result simultaneously and how it is deciding the values*" The interval you launched when `v =1` will only log `Output - 1`. Nothing else. The interval you launch when `v = 2` will only log `Output - 2`. Nothing else. You just have a bunch of intervals running.

Comment: @VLAZ apologies for that mistake

Comment: @VLAZ do you mind adding this as answer. I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval you launched when `v = 1` will only log `"Output - 1"`. Nothing else.

The interval you launch when `v = 2` will only log `"Output - 2"`. Nothing else.

Etc.

You just have a bunch of intervals running. Your code is essentially the same as:

```js
setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 1')
}, 2000 * 1);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 2')
}, 2000 * 2);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 3')
}, 2000 * 3);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 4')
}, 2000 * 4);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 5);
```

There is nothing about iterators that affects it. Only `let` matters because it creates separate variables each loop. For more explanation see:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
[Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

If you had used `var`, then there would be only *one* `i` and *one* `v` variable. So, your code would effectively be:

```
setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 1);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 2);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 3);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 4);

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log('Output - 5')
}, 2000 * 5);
```

This is because when calling `setInterval`, the time argument `2000 * (i + 1)` is based on `i` would be calculated with the value of `i` for the current iteration. However, by the time the delayed callback fires, `console.log('Output - ', v)` would only read the last value of `v`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is setting of multiple intervals - each iteration of the loop is setting a new interval which *closes* over a different value of `i` and each interval fires after a different time delay.

Each time interval callback is called, it logs the value it *closed* over when it was initially set up.

In your code, total of 5 intervals are setup and they fire at different times because of the specified time delay: `2000 * (i + 1)`.

> I am aware setTimeout will log a consistent result , but I intended to
> know why setInterval is logging two result simultaneously

That's because the interval which logs value 1 is fired multiple times *before* the interval that logs a larger value, for example 5 and that's simply because of the specified time delay: `2000 * (i + 1)`.

In the first iteration, value of `i` is 1 and the interval delay will be `2000 * (1 + 1)`.

Similarly, in the last iteration, value of `i` is 5 and the interval delay will be `2000 * (5 + 1)`.

As the delay for the interval set in the first iteration is larger, interval set in the first iteration will fire more than once *before* the interval set in the fifth iteration.

Use the same time delay for each interval to see the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

replace **setInterval** with **setTimeout**.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let [i, v] of numbers.entries()) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Output - ', v)
  }, 2000 * (i + 1))
}
```

You can learn more about it here: [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)